# Any way of ignoring grammatical inputs?

Tags: python, string, input

Below I have some code for a system that looks for keywords in sentences, I'm using the `.split()` extension for this task. It works fine but when I input the same keyword for example, "Hello." the full stop in my input doesn't match the codes so it returns an error. My question is that is there a way to allow grammatical inputs such as `.Upper()` and `.Lower()` allow for capital letters etc?

```
input1 = input("Input 'Hello'")
response = input1.split()

if "Hello" in response:
   print("Howdy!")
```

Output Error:

```
"Hello." is not defined.
```

Comment: You could `.strip()` non-letters, or use regular expressions.

Comment: Thanks, where would it go in my code?

Comment: This isn't the right place to explain regular expressions, for `.strip()`: `input1.strip('.!?')` will remove full stops, exclamation and question marks at the start and end of `input1`.

Comment: Oh I need something that still allows the "Howdy" to print even if the person inputs "Hello!!!!" **An input with grammatical characters in**

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to use `split` particularly - the `in` operator will check if one string is a substring of another. You could use the following:

```
input1 = input("Input 'Hello'").lower()

if "hello" in input1:
   print("Howdy!")
```

Which will return a message any time `hello` is included in the user's input, regardless of case or punctuation.

Comment: The only problem with that is that if someone inputs more than just "hello" it will return and error, like if someone inputted: "Hello system",

Comment: What version of Python are you using? If it's 2.7, you should use `raw_input` instead of `input`.

Comment: Yeah im using 3.5

Comment: Oh - you mean you don't want the message returning if any other words are included?

Comment: I just want the message to return even if the user inputs things like full stops or exclamation marks. For example a user could input: "Hello system!" and be returned with: "Howdy"

Comment: It should indeed return the print message in response to "Hello system!", as tested here https://repl.it/Eki2/0

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this using regular expressions, you can do something like:

```
import re
input1 = input("Input 'Hello'").lower() # from asongtoruin's answer
input1 = re.sub(r'[^\w]', '', input1) # replace everything not a word character with empty string

if input1 == "hello":
   print("Howdy!")
```

Which first filters out everything not a word, and then compares.

But like Jasper mentioned, it would be simpler to use `.strip()` if you know what the user will enter (although that wouldn't cover periods, etc. in the middle of the word)

```
input1 = input("Input 'Hello'").lower() # from asongtoruin's answer
input1 = input1.strip('.!?') # or try: strip(string.punctuation)

if input1 == "hello":
   print("Howdy!")
```

See [Best way to strip punctuation from a string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/265960/best-way-to-strip-punctuation-from-a-string-in-python) for further information..